# Bootstrap Navbar collapse moves to left and right when toggling hamburger button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I removed `padding-left` at class `.navbar-collapse.collapse.in` so the navigation looks more center. However, when I toggle the hamburger button, the navbar-collapse acts weirdly. 

When I try with the bootstrap `navbar-collapse` in smaller viewport, this bug isn't there. I recognize that this can be because I manually enable `navbar-collapse` to work with IPAD portrait with these code:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
        padding-left:0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
        padding-left:0;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float:none !important;
    }
}
```

I created a similar snippet of codes down here, the similar bug can be seen: 
http://codepen.io/ngp130895/pen/ZWMQqo 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because the padding become 0 when you toggle. If you add `padding: 15px` when the menu shows then it won't create that jurk.

Here is forked version - http://codepen.io/kalpeshsingh/pen/jqvWRa

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, I want the padding 0.

Comment: Why do you want padding zero? Any case?

Comment: Because I center the navigation items. 15px padding left will make them look not center

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I remove padding-left from class `navbar-collapse` as well.

```
.navbar-collapse {
   padding-left:0;
}
```

Bootstrap is kinda weird though.